# querying sys.database_principals accross a linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I'm attempting to get a listing of the users and roles they are associated with on a remote server to be input into a database on the local server.  But when I use the linked server sys.database_principals only shows me information for the login that the linked server is using.  How do I get a listing of users and roles by database to a central db location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sys.database_principals` and `sys.server_principals` are protected views.

From the [MSDN page on `sys.database_principals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx#Anchor_1):

> Any user can see their own user name, the system users, and the fixed database roles. To see other users, requires ALTER ANY USER, or a permission on the user. To see user-defined roles, requires ALTER ANY ROLE, or membership in the role.

You need to ensure the login used by the linked server has at least the `ALTER ANY USER` or `ALTER ANY ROLE` privilege in order to see the other principals.